# local space vs global space vs object space in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am watching [***this (game dev, space parenting & rotation)***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1xZGt41N80) 
Sebastian Lague video and found that there are **three spaces** actually (not two) and these are world space, local space and object space.

1. World space: The static space (0,0,0)
2. Object space: related to the object space
3. Local Space: related to the parent of the object

I am amazed that i didn't find the distinction between these two spaces(local and object) on official unity forms but actually it exists. My question is that why there is no Space.Local? I found that there are Space. Self and Space.World.
Space.Self is refer to object space. I can move my object to object space using this

```
    void Update () {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0,0,1) * Time.deltaTime * 2,Space.Self);
    }
```

And i can move my object to world space using this

```
void Update () {
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(0,0,1) * Time.deltaTime * 2,Space.World);
}
```

but there is no support for local space that i could move the object to local space (means move the object related to its parent object). There is a fair distinction between Local and Object space but unity didn't consider it i guess or i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the Unity's inspector, the position and rotation of the Transform component are **relative to the parent** (defined in the local space)

The axes represented by the gizmo handles are either the global ones (world space) or the **object ones** as pointed out by S. Lague in the video.

The local axes (axes of the parent Transform) are not represented when you select a gameobject, contrary to other 3D softwares (like Maya I think), and there is no C# function to translate in the local space but you can create one:

```
Vector3 right     = transform.parent.right;
Vector3 up        = transform.parent.up ;
Vector3 forward   = transform.parent.forward;
Vector3 direction = X * right + Y * up + Z * forward ;

transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

However, keep in mind that an object `A` will **always** have a position and rotation of (0, 0, 0), in object space because the latter **is** defined by the object itself. An object `A` can't be moved / rotated from **itself**.

Comment: "The local axes [...] are not represented when you select a gameobject"

You can [change from global to local](https://imgur.com/CPhz7IE) but it's true that you cannot do that in inspector.

"no C# function to translate in the local space"

Well yes, no "Translate" call, but you can set the transform.localPosition. 

Also note: Whenever you ask for transform.position - you get the global position, even if the object is deep down in the hierarchie. 

For directions, there is [InverseTransformDirection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html)

Comment: No, the local axes are not represented. You can either visualize the global axes or the **object axes**.
You can indeed set the locaPosition, but the OP asked how to set the localPosition using the local (parent) axes .

Comment: Sorry but i am unable to understand your last paragraph. Can you define it a bit more?

Comment: setting localPosition or rotation will be happened according to the parent? or object space?

Comment: The **object space** is the [Euclidian space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) defined by an object. The origin of the space is the origin of the object. Thus, if you move the object, you also move the origin of the space. The same way, if you rotate the object, you rotate the axes of the object space. Therefore, the object will always have a position of (0,0,0) and a rotation of (0,0,0) in the space it defines.

Comment: Setting the localPosition of the object sets the position of the object **relative to the parent**. If you call `transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,1,0)`, the object will be 1 unit far from the parent object **along the Y axis of the parent object**